# Have VS2010 use IE9 to open XBAPs even though Chrome is my default browser

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, xbap

Google Chrome is set as my default browser (on Windows 7). However, when I compile and run an XBAP application in Visual Studio 2010, I'd like it to run in IE9. Currently, VS2010 tries to view it in Chrome.

Is there a way to have VS2010 use IE9 for XBAP projects?

My current workaround is to set IE9 as my default browser while testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  could use [Default Browser Switcher VS extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bb424812-f742-41ef-974a-cdac607df921) to change browser to run you site in VS.

Answer (score 3):

Not by default.

There's a [Visual Studio extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bb424812-f742-41ef-974a-cdac607df921/) that you could use for this.

I think that there will be a better built-in experience in Visual Studio vNext ([source](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/FeaturesNOONENOTICEDInVisualStudio11ExpressBetaForWeb.aspx))

Comment: Thanks for the source link Jon. Good to know this feature is on the way.